# How to remove start of a string using pure "regular expression"

Tags: regex, string, replace

I am very new to regular expressions and lets just say I am finding them infuriating.

I have a simple requirement where I simply want to transform the following string

**INO_ROLE_CF_SBX_rest-of-string** to **rest-of-string**

by removing prefix **INO_ROLE_CF_SBX_**

What is the most efficient way to achieve this, without calling other "functions" that do the work for me.

Any advice offered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need:

```js
const input = "INO_ROLE_CF_SBX_rest-of-string";

const result = /^INO_ROLE_CF_SBX_(.*)$/.exec(input)[1];

console.log(result);
```